# insert result of dynamic pivot query into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, temp-tables, dynamicquery

I have a dynamic pivot query

```
     SELECT * FROM (SELECT [SERVICEID],
                    [SERVICETYPEID],[TRAIN],[SERVICETYPEOPTIONID], 
                    [OPTIONNAME], [CLIENTID],[AGENT],  [MANAGEMENTLEGID ],   
                    [LEG],   [ALLOCATIONDATE],[CURRENTALLOCATION] 
   FROM EXCELEXPORT) AS [SubTable]  PIVOT (MAX([CURRENTALLOCATION])FOR [ALLOCATIONDATE] IN ( [02/05/19], [02/07/19], [02/08/19], [02/09/19], [02/10/19]) ) AS [Pivot];
```

which needs to be inserted into temp table.How can i achieve it.Any inputs would be valauble.

Comment: what is the purpose of the `temp table` ? Can you just return the result set back to the calling application ?

Comment: because i will be updating certain fields in temp table.

Comment: You need to reconsider how you want to do all this. What you want is not possible with temp table. Once it gets out of scope it is gone. One alternative is to use global temp table but you will need to use a create the global temp table with dynamic name else it will conflict

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert the result of `EXEC sp_executesql` into a temporary table, you need to first defined the definition of your table.

And as your dynamic T-SQL statement can lead to different numbers of columns returned you are not about to define the table in advanced.

Actually, you can define such table in advance using T-SQL statement, but it not be visible in other `sp_execuetsql` execution or the outer scope:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE TABLE #DataSource ([column] int)';

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM #DataSource';

SELECT *
FROM #DataSource;
```

So, the only choice you have is to wrap all of your logic in dynamic T-SQL statement and then return the result.

Answer (score 0):

A PIVOT used to rotate the data from one column into multiple columns.

Here is [DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/521090) using temp table to deal with PIVOT query

Comment: @muhammad..i want specific to my query..i am new to dynamic queries.thanks

Comment: kindly share sample data to let me know about data type of each column